# Deserialize array in array with json.NET in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have an REST API which delivers in json format.
The json looks like this

```
[{"user":{"name":"foo","url":"bar"}}
  ,[{"product":{"name":"banana","price":"85"}},
  {"product":{"name":"peach","price":"66"}},
  {"product":{"name":"strawberry","price":"78"}}]]
```

How can I transfer this with json.NET?

I tried some varients of

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

but it won't work with `Product p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(e.Result);`

How do I declare both classes? Sorry, but http://json2csharp.com/ didn't work.

Comment: Little confused on what you're asking for. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: sorry about that. i edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to create a model in C# from JSON

```
public class User
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string url { get; set; }
   public List<Product> product { get; set; }

}

 public class Product
 {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Decimal price { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But then I try to get my products like this: 'User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(e.Result);
            List<Product> product = user.product;' but the user is null.

Comment: User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(e.Result[0]);